# Why doesn't FONTSIGNATURE reflect lfCharSet?

Tags: windows, fonts, gdi, uniscribe

I'm enumerating Windows fonts like this:

```
LOGFONTW lf = {0};
lf.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
lf.lfFaceName[0] = L'\0';
lf.lfPitchAndFamily = 0;
::EnumFontFamiliesEx(hdc, &lf,
                     reinterpret_cast<FONTENUMPROCW>(FontEnumCallback),
                     reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this), 0);
```

My callback function has this signature:

```
int CALLBACK FontEnumerator::FontEnumCallback(const ENUMLOGFONTEX *pelf,
                                              const NEWTEXTMETRICEX *pMetrics,
                                              DWORD font_type,
                                              LPARAM context);
```

For TrueType fonts, I typically get each face name multiple times.  For example, for multiple calls, I'll get `pelf->elfFullName` and `pelf->elfLogFont.lfFaceName` set as `"Arial"`.  Looking more closely at the other fields, I see that each call is for a different script.  For example, on the first call `pelf->elfScript` will be `"Western"` and `pelf->elfLogFont.lfCharSet` will be the numeric equivalent of `ANSI_CHARSET`.  On the second call, I get `"Hebrew"` and `HEBREW_CHARSET`.  Third call `"Arabic"` and `ARABIC_CHARSET`.  And so on.  So far, so good.

But the [font signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318064(VS.85).aspx) (`pMetrics->ntmFontSig`) field for all versions of Arial is identical.  In fact, the font signature claims that all of these versions of Arial support Latin-1, Hebrew, Arabic, and others.

I know the character sets of the strings I'm trying to draw, so I'm trying to instantiate an appropriate font based on the font signatures.  Because the font signatures always match, I always end up selecting the "Western" font, even when displaying Hebrew or Arabic text.  I'm using low level Uniscribe APIs, so I don't get the benefit of Windows font linking, and yet my code seems to work.

Does `lfCharSet` actually carry any meaning or is it a legacy artifact? Should I just set `lfCharSet` to `DEFAULT_CHARSET` and stop worrying about all the script variations of each face?

For my purposes, I only care about TrueType and OpenType fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer.  Fonts that get enumerated multiple times are ["big" fonts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194830(v=MSDN.10).aspx).  Big fonts are single fonts that include glyphs for multiple scripts or code pages.

The Unicode portion of the [`FONTSIGNATURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318064(VS.85).aspx) (`fsUsb`) represents all the Unicode subranges that the font can handle.  This is independent of the character set.  If you use the wide character APIs, you can use all the included glyphs in the font, regardless of which character set was specified when you create the font.

The code page portion of the `FONTSIGNATURE` (`fsCsb`) represents the code pages that the font can handle.  I believe this is only significant when the font is not a "big" font.  In that case, the `fsUsb` masks will be all zeros, and the `fsCsb` will specify the appropriate character set(s).  In those cases, it's important to get the `lfCharSet` correct in the `LOGFONT`.

When instantiating a "big" font and using the wide character APIs, it apparently doesn't matter which `lfCharSet` you specify.